# Displaying extra custom information in the shopify admin dashboard panel

Tags: php, laravel, shopify, development-environment, shopify-app

I have added one custom field (phone number) while creating an account, but I am unable to show it in admin dashboard. I have added ShopifyFD addon, but it is still not showing. How to show that extra field in dashboard?

```
<label> Phone</label>
<input size="30" type="tel" name="customer[note][phone]" 
                                       id="customer_phone" placeholder="Phone Test" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Shopify admin dashboard is changed with react, i installed shopifyFD chrome extension, not working for me. I think they will provide update that will compatible with new shopify admin.